# Laravel HTML helper and multi-lingual definition lists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'm building a multi-lingual site in Laravel 3 and was trying to use the HTML helper for creating definition lists. This works by using key/value pairs to represent the dt and dd respectively.

### Example

```
echo HTML::dl(array('Ubuntu' => 'An operating system by Canonical', 'Windows' => 'An operating system by Microsoft'));
```

Each of my dt elements needs to contain a translated string. But if I try to create my array like this:

```
array(__('core.dt_title') => $dd_value);
```

I get an illegal offset error.

Anyone know a way around this issue?

Comment: An *illegal offset* type error occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key. Seems like `__('core.dt_title')` is not returning a string as it would normally do.

Comment: can you print out the value of `__('core.dt_title')`... just do something like `dd(__('core.dt_title'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rubens mentioned, the `__` helper is returning a Lang object and not a string.
To fix your problem, simply replace `__('core.dt_title')` with `__('core.dt_title')->get()`

Comment: I'm kicking myself - that should have been very obvious! I was quite tired though :) Thanks!